# Best way to pass mutate state in children components then use it in the parent component and use memoization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, performance, react-hooks

I have  a  page that is compiled with 3 form components I want the parent page to have the state and pass through the  state to child components  then I want to mutate  the state in the forms and then  use  them in the parent component  I currently doing it in a way similar to as shown below but I am not sure if this is the best approach to handle  state in child components  is there a better way ?
Also I want to memoize the form components with react.memo to prevent them from re-rendering  unless the props have changed. Any help would be much appreciated

```
const [form1, setform1] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [Form2, setform2] = useState<string>("");
const [form3, setForm3] = useState({});
<form1 form1={form1} setfrom1={setform1} otherProps={otherProps} />
<form2 form2={form2} setfrom2={setform2} otherProps={otherProps} />
<form3 form3={form3} setfrom1={setform3} otherProps={otherProps}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use Context API. If your other props are similar for your forms it will be the best solution for your.